# should .nx be in git ignore? (nx monorepo)

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl, nomachine-nx, nx-monorepo

I recently upgraded my Nx monorepo workspace from v13 to v16 using the `nx migrate` command and did the required modifications manually. The command added an .nx folder with a cache subfolder:

[image]

The nx migrate command didn't add the cache folder to `.gitignore`. While I don't think local caches should be version controlled and committed to git, the folder contains other files with meaningful names (`nxdeps.json`, `file-map.json`, etc.) that I'm not sure if they are mandatory for the upgraded nx version.

Should I add `.nx/cache` to my `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, after continuing the upgrade from Nx v16 to v17, the migration tool automatically added `.nx/cache` to `.gitignore`

[image]

However, if you've already committed file(s) from `.nx/cache`, remember to remove it from Git's tracking system by running:

```
git rm -r --cached .nx/cache
git commit -m "Stop tracking .nx/cache directory"
```

otherwise just adding the folder to .gitignore won't do the work.